# scala nested self types

Tags: scala, self-type

Why doesn't this work:

```
scala> trait A
defined trait A

scala> class Z {
     | this: A =>
     | }
defined class Z

scala> class Y {
     | this: A =>
     | val z = new Z()
     | }
<console>:11: error: class Z cannot be instantiated because it does not conform to its self-type Z with A
       val z = new Z()
```

I want the A that is mixed into Y to be again mixed into the instance of Z in Y.  How can I do that?

EDIT (was trying to be too brief in the above example.  Here's my actual problem):

```
scala> import scala.slick.driver.ExtendedProfile
import scala.slick.driver.ExtendedProfile

scala> class Z {
     | this: ExtendedProfile =>
     | }
defined class Z

scala> class Y {
     | this: ExtendedProfile =>
     | val z = new Z() with ExtendedProfile
     | }
<console>:21: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type Z with scala.slick.driver.ExtendedProfile does not conform to scala.slick.driver.ExtendedProfile's selftype scala.slick.driver.ExtendedDriver
       val z = new Z() with ExtendedProfile
                        ^
```

I guess I understand why that doesn't compile, but shouldn't this be implicit (not actual scala keyword 'implicit', just generally implicit ;) )?  If an ExtendedProfile always must have an ExtendedDriver, why is new Z() complaining that it needs an ExtendedDriver?

FYI: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0-RC1/api/#scala.slick.driver.ExtendedProfile

Comment: `new Z() with A` perhaps?

Comment: @om-nom-nom suggestion will surely compile. But I am not sure it's Lester's intentions.

Comment: Because the fact that Y is a ExtendedProfile doesn't make its members also a ExtendedProfiles. The same goes for A in your illustrative example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile error says that you need to provide an `A` mix-in to instantiate a `Z` object. As om-non-nom suggests, your code compiles with a small change,

```
trait A

class Z { this: A =>
}

class Y { this: A =>
  val z = new Z with A
}
```

Here's an alternative that uses inheritance instead of a self-type, and may be closer to your intentions:

```
trait Y extends A {
  val z = new Z with Y
}
```

**EDIT**

To answer your updated question, the self-type is a *constraint* on the type construction. Self-types are different from inheritance in that they *don't extend* the type's external interface.

From the Scaladoc you linked, it looks like this is the situation:

```
trait ExtendedDriver extends ExtendedProfile
trait ExtendedProfile { self: ExtendedDriver => }

class Z { this: ExtendedProfile => }

class Y {
  this: ExtendedProfile =>
  val z = new Z() with ExtendedProfile
}
```

The problem is that `ExtendedProfile` does not inherit from `ExtendedDriver`, so it can't stand alone; it needs to be provided an explicit `ExtendedDriver`. You can do that with

```
new Z() with ExtendedProfile with ExtendedDriver
```

That's actually redundant, since `ExtendedProfile` is already mixed in. You simply need,

```
new Z() with ExtendedDriver
```

Comment: Thanks.  I updated my question with what's actually happening.